# como actualizo pip en python3 linux

Tags: python-3.x, pip, tensorflow

como puedo actualizar pip en python3 en linux  es que quiero instalar tersorflow y creo que es que tengo que actualizar pip

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow! Te invito a hacer el [tour], dónde aprenderás como funciona el sitio y, de paso, ganarás tu primera medalla.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Actualizar pip

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Instalar tensorflow

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow
```